# Images section in editing help page contains only "http://" examples

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, ssl, editing-help

In editing help page, in ["Images"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images) section there are few examples with the URL. All the URLs are with the `http://` only. When tried those example in the editor we received the "All image URLs must start with **https://**" error.

The following are the URLs from the "Images" section:

- `![Valid XHTML](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10).`
- `<img src="http://example.com/sample.png" width="100" height="100">`
- > [image: error url]

Can all the example URLs be updated with "**https://**"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the urls used on this page are now prefixed with `https://`.

> want commonmark help?
> go to images help page
> examples secure